# Merge 2 armatures and 2 meshes then parent the armature to the mesh, without losing their weight paints?

Tags: modeling, bones, weight-painting

I have 2 arms i made separately and i copied it, but when i merge the meshes and bones and then reparent the bones to the mesh, one bone is weighing both arms, but the other isnt doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably a naming issue :

- the armature will create vertex groups with the bones names
- when you join the meshes groups with the same name get merged
- when you join armatures bones will get new names if other with the same name exist
- so you end up with one armature controlling both meshes

to avoid this ensure that your armature bones have different names before parenting each mesh to the armature